# facing /usr/lib/libpcap.so: undefined reference to `pcap_lex' while running make command nprobe

Tags: libpcap, netflow

I am trying to install nprobe on my system when i followed the following steps

```
git clone https://github.com/xrl/nprobe.git
sudo apt-get install libpcap-dev
cd nprobe/plugsins
./buildMakefile.sh  >Makefile.in
cd ..
./autogen.sh 
./configure
  make
```

all above commands run absolutely fine but when i try to run make its give me the    following error.
    usr/lib/libpcap.so: undefined reference to `pcap_lex'
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Did libpcap come with your OS, or did you build and install it yourself?  If it came with the OS, what OS is it, and what version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah... we came across this with our netflow exporter. You need to have `flex` installed (the GNU implementation of UNIX `lex`). You'll probably also need to install `bison`, and I think it might use `m4` too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that not only libpcap-devel need to be installed, but also libpcap.